# Jolt - issue with combined values when added at same level

Tags: json, apache-camel, jolt

I am new to using jolt

Currently facing issues combining array of maps.

I have an array of maps, 1 key in each map has an array of strings - **as shown in input JSON.**

I am trying to combine all the key/values into single array of maps -
**as shown in expected output**

When combined the values are getting merged rather than being adding separately.

Any help is appreciated.

**Input JSON**

```
 {
  "items": [
    {
      "frontItem": [
        "frontItem1"
      ],
      "base": "base1"
    },
    {
      "frontItem": [
        "frontItem2",
        "frontItem3"
      ],
      "base": "base2"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Jolt Spec created**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "items": {
        "*": {
          "frontItem": {
            "*": {
              "@": "modified-items.[&].frontItem",
              "@(2,base)": "modified-items.[&].base"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Expected output**

```
{
  "modified-items": [
    {
      "frontItem": "frontItem1",
      "base": "base1"
    },
    {
      "frontItem": "frontItem2",
      "base": "base2"
    },
    {
      "frontItem": "frontItem3",
      "base": "base2"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Current output with spec created**

```
{
  "modified-items": [
    {
      "frontItem": [
        "frontItem1",
        "frontItem2"
      ],
      "base": [
        "base1",
        "base2"
      ]
    },
    {
      "frontItem": "frontItem3",
      "base": "base2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're so close to reach the solution. Just seperate the values by **`@(3,base)`** while walking through the indexes of the **`frontItem`** list such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "items": {
        "*": {
          "frontItem": {
            "*": {
              "@": "@(3,base).[&].frontItem",
              "@(2,base)": "@(3,base).[&].base"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/

[image]